# How to return function in document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if it is possible to do this, like I have 2 js files.
The first Js File:

```
var news_pos, about_pos, services_pos, clients_pos;

function define_pos() {

    var $top_slides=$('#top_slides'), 
        $mid_nav=$('#mid_nav'), 
        $news_section=$('#section-1');

    var fixed_height = $top_slides.height() + $mid_nav.height();

    news_pos = fixed_height - 20;
    about_pos = fixed_height + $news_section.height();
    services_pos = fixed_height + $news_section.height() * 2;
    clients_pos = fixed_height + $news_section.height() * 3;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var section_news = $('#section-1'),
        section_about = $('#section-2'),
        section_services = $('#section-3'),
        section_clients = $('#section-4');

    setheight();

    function setheight() {
        var section_height = $(window).height() + 200;
        $section_news.height(section_height);
        $section_about.height(section_height); 
        $section_services.height(section_height);
        $section_clients.height(section_height);
        define_pos();
    }
});
```

1. The second JS File:

   $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
   var nav = {

       '$btn1': $('#btn1'),
       '$btn2': $('#btn2'),
       '$btn3': $('#btn3'),
       '$btn4': $('#btn4'),
       '$btn5': $('#btn5'), 

       myclick : function() {

           myclicked(nav.$btn1, 0);
           myclicked(nav.$btn2, news_pos);
           myclicked(nav.$btn3, about_pos);
           myclicked(nav.$btn4, services_pos);
           myclicked(nav.$btn5, clients_pos);

           function myclicked(j,k) {
               j.click(function(e) {    
                   e.preventDefault();
                   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: k}, 1000);
               });
           }
           // Is it right to do return{'myclick':myclick}, 
           // how to call? seems not logical
       }
   };

   // Here will not work because it say news_pos is undefined.
   // If I use setTimeout(nav.myclick,1000), it will works but
   // I want to run it right the when position is caculated.
   nav.myclick();
   ```

   });

How do I pass the nav.myclick() function to the frist js file and put it in setheight() and under define_pos()?
By the way writing codes right in stackoverflow is strange,press tab not really give you any spacing.

Comment: _Always_ convert tabs to spaces before pasting code anywhere, otherwise you can see what happens with your indentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `function setheight(){ }` is an internal function in the first `$(document).ready(function(){}`.  Its "scope" (visibility) is limited to inside that function.

To make it visible to everyone, you need to move it outside of `$(document).ready(function(){}`.

Then, declare the first file *before* the second one, and functions in the second file can now use `setheight()`.

---

To use `myClick`:

Your function now is `myclicked()` so you need to change that to `myclick()`.  Then, you can call the functions in the global scope:

```
function myclick(j,k){            
    j.click(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: k}, 1000);
    setheight();
    define_pos();
}
```

Comment: umm, but can't I just return my private function for the global to use? I don't want to put too many things to global,I want to keep the set height in document ready

Comment: Yes, to do that you'll need to write it in JSON format, something like `return {myclick : function() { ...stuff... }}`

Comment: You can also declare a namespace, to avoid using the global one. But both of these are more advanced topics in Javascript, if you're just learning the global scope is sufficient.

Comment: ...and you've already got `define_pos()` in the global namespace anyway.

Comment: can I  return {'nav.myclick' : nav.myclick()}; and call it global in another file using document.ready.nav.myclick(); ? but sounds weird

Comment: @FatDogMark - I've added another answer with a way you can namespace, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to namespace your position functions per your "new" question in the comments. It's pure JS, not JQuery, but it's the same anyway:

```
var POSITIONING = {
    news_pos : 0,
    about_pos : 0,
    services_pos : 0,
    clients_pos : 0,

    define_pos : function() {
         var fixed_height = 100;

         POSITIONING.news_pos     = fixed_height; // + whatever
         POSITIONING.about_pos    = fixed_height; // + whatever
         POSITIONING.services_pos = fixed_height; // + whatever
         POSITIONING.clients_pos  = fixed_height; // + whatever
    },

    set_height : function() {
        alert(this.news_pos)
    }
};
```

Put this in a JS file, load it before any other files that use it, and call as follows:

```
// For example, when the window loads...or document is ready, whatever
window.onload = function() {
    POSITIONING.define_pos();
    POSITIONING.set_height();
};
```

It's also worth noting that it looks like this could be done more efficiently with CSS using a margin or padding or something.  Probably a lot easier.

Comment: But it should be impossible to make a div height same as user window height just by css , so using return a function to global is not possible in document ready,must have to declare in global.. but I tried declare an object in global it wont find the jquery elements.. although I solved it by moving the function in proper places in order and put them into one same file